# Is this energy usage for safari normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, power-management

I was checking my activity monitor for Safari, and I see this number as its average energy usage. Is it normal?

[image]

Comment: The pop-up message when you hover over the Average Energy Impact header is "Average Energy Impact in the past 12 hours or since the Mac restarted. Lower is better." I would assume that if you've not restarted your Mac in weeks (or months), and use Safari regularly, this number would get large.

Answer (score 1):

It is not normal according to the "Avg Energy Impact" column. It is awkward to have more than 10,000 value for the "Avg Energy Impact" column, especially from Safari. Please contact [Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/) if you see this consistently.

You should consider the "*Energy Impact*" column as it shows the real-time energy usage. 

The "*Avg Energy Impact*" column shows the average energy impact for the past 8 hours or since the Mac started up, whichever is shorter.

For more info : [Apple Documentation - Activity Monitor](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201464)